# Dotnet compiler giving Dereference of a possibly null reference only for first array of nullable array

Tags: c#, asp.net, warnings, nullable-reference-types

I am running an asp.net core application , I have a class with a string array member which i have declared as nullable.
When i am using the array elements in my other classes, the compiler gives me Dereference of a possibly null reference warning only for the first member of the array and not for the others.

PS sorry for bad formatting of the code. There are no syntax errors

I am getting a warning for possible null values for DummyData[0] but not for DummyData[1] and others.

```
public class Dummy
{
    public string[]? DummyData { get; set; }
}
```

This is where i am using DummyData

```
result += DummyDataConstants.SOM + DummyDataConstants.cmdMainArray[(int)DummyDataConstants.CMD_MAIN_ID_e.CMD_MAIN_REQ_LOG]
                                    + DummyDataConstants.FSP + DummyDataConstants.SMART_CODE + DummyDataConstants.FSP + commandParams.DummyData[0]  // warning given for commandParams.DummyData[0] 

+ DummyDataConstants.FSP + commandParams.DummyData[1]  // no warning here
+ DummyDataConstants.FSP + commandParams.MediaClientType + DummyDataConstants.FSP + commandParams.DummyData[2] + DummyDataConstants.FSP + newGuid.ToString() + DummyDataConstants.FSP + DummyDataConstants.EOM
```

Comment: If the value _was_ null, an exception would be thrown the first time it was accessed..? Not sure what you're asking here?

Comment: I think it shows the warning only on the first possible occurrence of a `NullReferenceException` (because if it crashes in your first statement then it can't crash in your second statement since it will never be reached).

Comment: The message isn't telling you that `DummyData[0]` may be null, it's saying the entire `DummyData` property may be null. You have a nullable array of non-nullable strings, perhaps you are getting confused with `string?[]` which is a non-nullable array of nullable strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler will emit warning only when your code may dereference `null`. In this case only place where this is considered to be possible is `commandParams.DummyData[0]` since if it is (i.e. `commandParams.DummyData == null`) you will encounter `NullReferenceException` here, hence all other attempts either will not happen or will work with definitely not null reference. If you will use [null-conditional element access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) for the first element you will see the warning "transferred" to the next one:

```
void WarningTest(int[]? array)
{
     Console.WriteLine(array?[0]);   
     Console.WriteLine(array[0]); // warning 
     Console.WriteLine(array[0]); // no warning 
}
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ65IJwAoBEgPBuAg+/gJQDc6mALAAQDqAhmFAJZQDmAKgKYDOwXB2ABtALoB+OizBMAnmXQBvdHXXqseWQsmiADOMoa1Gultw75BoxToB6e3QDuLdlzqmNFqzeOO6KAB7FzcOTk80AF8gA=)